# HTML: How do I prevent mp3 file to get downloaded used in embed tag

Tags: asp.net, html, html5-audio

I am using embed tag to play background music on my web. It works fine on IE but on Mozilla, and Chrome it gets downloaded. What will be the work around?

My tag is

```
 <embed 
    src="http://www.abc.com/xyz.mp3" 
    autostart="true" 
    loop="true" 
    hidden="true"/>
```

I tried HTML `<audio>` tag but page stopped responding.

**Please note, my mp3 file is on some remote server, not on my websites directory.**

Comment: Use some mp3 player made with flash.

Comment: is no Answer acceptable for you? if you have found a better solution? if so please share. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aristos commented you could use a flash player as flowplayer

```
<a id="mb" style="display:block;width:648px;height:30px;"
href="/media/data/fake_empire.mp3"></a>

<script>
$f("mb", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf", {

// fullscreen button not needed here
plugins: {
    controls: {
        fullscreen: false,
        height: 30,
        autoHide: false
    }
},

clip: {
    autoPlay: false,
    // optional: when playback starts close the first audio playback
    onBeforeBegin: function() {
        $f("player").close();
    }

}

});
</script>
```

(http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/audio.html)

the Audio Tag works only on "new" browsers

```
...

<audio src="http://xxxx/xxxx/xxx.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" />

...
```

If not you would have to check via javascript which browser is running and react accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best way to do this but for the specific problem you got here might be related with the server that stores your mp3 file. If it sends the file content to client side with http header Content-Disposition it can make this happen. Please check section **19.5.1 Content-Disposition** at [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html), basically it tells the browser to download the file directly but not open it.

For verify that, you can use some tool like [Fillder](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) do see what's the response of that mp3 file request really looks like.

For solve this you may need to figure out a way to not let that server send the Content-Disposition header, or change to use a different content server do not send Content-Disposition header.

Answer (score 0):

Why not sue the [<audio>](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) tag, which is fairly standard by now?

I **think** most browsers find a way to support mp3 depending on codec availability.